# ERROR: function shortest_path(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist

Tags: pgrouting

I have my roads and locations added into my PostGis DB, and have installed pgRouting's SQL files. However, when I attempt to run:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
   SELECT gid AS id, 
          start_id::int4 AS source, 
          end_id::int4 AS target, 
          shape_leng::float8 AS cost
   FROM myr_roads_point',
1,
5110,
false,
false);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  function shortest_path(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function shortest_path(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 15
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your error hints that you haven't installed pgrouting.Can you confirm the validity of your installation? http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html

Comment: The steps is for Linux, whereas I'm running on Windows... So I'm not too sure I have it installed properly..?

Answer (score 2):

Check your PostgreSQL version, because pgRouting does not work with versions after 8.4.

Comment: There is support for 9.1 version. check this link http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you still having that problem check out this link:
http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=pgrouting_osm2po_1#305
I have used the latest binary of pgrouting - it has more explanation what to do. Also to test the capabilities of db - copy SQL stat from the QGIS error and execute as a SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As 'nickves' commented, maybe you haven't loaded the pgRouting functions into your database.

I don't know exactly where the files containing the functions are located on Windows, but the file names should be the same as [described in the workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#load-functions).

You can easily load them with pgAdmin3 for example.

You can either check if the functions exists by looking into the `public` schema of your database using pgAdmin3, or with `\df shortest_path` command in the psql shell.

Comment: Nope - Shortest_path is not inside- but i can see other functions like dijkstra_sp, shootingstar_ap, etc, which means that the pgRouting SQL has already been ran on my DB, but for some reason did not create the Shortest_path...

I also noticed that there is 3 DLL files as part of the pgRouting download, and I placed it under C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgresPlus\9.0SS\lib (cos the documentation didn't state where I should put the files...)